# Select Custom Markers on Google Maps by drawing a circle

Tags: javascript, google-maps

I am working on a project in which I want to be able to select my custom marker on google maps by drawing a circle on the map. All the markers in the encompassed circle should be selected. Here is how it is going to go:

```
1. User clicks at a point on googlemaps and draws a circle.
2. The circle encompasses the custom markers.
3. All the custom markers are selected.
```

I need to go through with these 3 steps.

Help needed.

Comment: What trouble are you having doing that?  What have you done so far?

Comment: I have added my markers on to google maps. I have also used the code to draw a circle. now I am confused on how to select locations under my circle.

Comment: Locations that are less than the radius of the circle away from its center are in the circle.

Comment: Yes, I want to get them in a result set.

Comment: Are you planning on using some particular kind of software? What do you mean by "a result set"?

Comment: My flow is like this: 
get locations from mysql > geocode them and place markers on google maps > select by drawing a circle on the maps > take Id's of all markers in circle > search database for information on the Id's > display information.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

possible workflow:

1. when you create the markers, store them in an object (use the ID's as property-name).
    sample:

   ```
   markers = {
     1: new google.maps.Marker(/*properties*/),
     2: new google.maps.Marker(/*properties*/),
     5: new google.maps.Marker(/*properties*/)
   }
   ```
2. when the `Circle` has been drawn fetch `radius` and `center` of the circle
3. iterate over the `markers`-properties and use [`google.maps.geometry.spherical.computeDistanceBetween`](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#spherical) to filter the markers. Store the ID's of the filtered markers in an array:

   ```
    var IDs=[];

    for(var k in markers){
        if(google.maps.geometry.spherical
           .computeDistanceBetween(circleCenter,markers[k].getPosition())
             <=circleRadius){
           IDs.push(k);
        }
    }
   ```
4. Send the IDs-array to your serverside script.....

**Note:** the `geometry`-library isn't loaded by default, see https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/libraries

Comment: This is really cool. I got the basic but I want that as soon as I draw the circle an event should triggered so that I can extract my Id's. I am day 1 Javascript person so need some hints.

Comment: got the google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'click', function(e). Hope I am right!

Comment: assuming that you use the drawing-library: there will fire a [`circle_complete`](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/drawing#drawing_events)-event